# Error implementing Angular Factory and Service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a beginner in Angular JS, i am trying to implement it to retrieve values from a dishes array to display it in view page. Somewhere the code is going wrong and the the information is not showing in the view page, though it appears in the log.

My HTML page below:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in dish">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="media" >
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object"
                     ng-src={{food.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{food.name}}
                     <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{food.label}}</span>
                     <span class="badge">{{food.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                    <p>{{food.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h4>Customer comments &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <small>  Sort by <input type="text" ng-model="sortBy"></small></h4>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
             <li>
            <blockquote ng-repeat="commen in food.comments|orderBy:sortBy">
            <p>{{commen.rating}} Stars</p>
              <p>{{commen.comment}}</p>
              <footer>{{commen.author}}  <cite>{{commen.date| date:'mediumDate'}}</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
            </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

and my controller.js script below and its included in the html page before body close tag

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {                
   $scope.sortBy="";
   $scope.dish= menuFactory.getDish(3);
   console.log($scope.dish);     
}])
```

and finally below is the services.js script, included before body close tag

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')
    .factory('menuFactory', function() {

    var menufac = {};

    var dishes=[


        {             name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains',
                       label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }]                                                          
                     },
                    {
                      name:'Zucchipakoda',
                       image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                      category: 'appetizer',
                       label:'',
                      price:'1.99',
                      description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                      comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }]                                                         
                    },
                    {
                      name:'Vadonut',
                       image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                      category: 'appetizer',
                       label:'New',
                      price:'1.99',
                      description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }]

                    },
                    {
                      name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                       image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                      category: 'dessert',
                       label:'',
                      price:'2.99',
                      description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }]                                                        

                        }



                     ];


                menufac.getDishes = function(){
                                    return dishes;
                                };
                menufac.getDish = function (index) {
                                    return dishes[index];
            };

                return menufac;


    });
```

Comment: Did you have any error in console?

Comment: @Mistalis No, there was no error in the console. It was displaying the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

If you want to display all the dishes you have to give an array to ng-repeat:

In your controller, replace getDishes(3) by getDishes() :

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {                
   $scope.sortBy="";
   $scope.dish= menuFactory.getDishes();
   console.log($scope.dish);     
}])
```

Maybe you can rename dish in dishes :

```
$scope.dishes= menuFactory.getDishes();
```

And in the html:

```
ng-repeat = "food in dishes"
```

Solution 2:

if you want to display just one "dish", just remove the ng-repeat="food in dish"

Comment: Yeah, i figured this out :) Thanks a lot for this. I was assuming there would be some directive to display single value of an array.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` directive needs an array:

```
<!-- ERRONEOUS
<div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in dish">
-->

<!-- DO THIS -->
<div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in [dish]">

<!-- OR -->
<div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in dishes">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
<div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in dishes">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="media" >
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object"
                 ng-src={{food.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">{{food.name}}
                 <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{food.label}}</span>
                 <span class="badge">{{food.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                <p>{{food.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
        <h4>Customer comments &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <small>  Sort by <input type="text" ng-model="sortBy"></small></h4>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li>
        <blockquote ng-repeat="commen in food.comments|orderBy:sortBy">
        <p>{{commen.rating}} Stars</p>
          <p>{{commen.comment}}</p>
          <footer>{{commen.author}}  <cite>{{commen.date| date:'mediumDate'}}</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
        </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```